# Problem with opencv (cv2) detecting motion in my code

Tags: python, opencv

I have written a code to detect motion through a webcam but whenever I start the code, it works but it detects the entire full screen instead of objects moving in the screen. I noticed that if I close the camera it seems to remove the detection; Here is the code:

```
import cv2

first_frame = None

video = cv2.VideoCapture(0)

while True:
    check, frame = video.read()

    gray = cv2.cvtColor(frame, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
    gray = cv2.GaussianBlur(gray, (21,21),0)

    if first_frame is None:
        first_frame=gray
        continue

    delta_frame = cv2.absdiff(first_frame,gray)
    thresh_frame = cv2.threshold(delta_frame, 30, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY)[1]
    thresh_frame = cv2.dilate(thresh_frame,None, iterations=2)

    (cnts,_) = cv2.findContours(thresh_frame.copy(), cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)

    for contour in cnts:
        if cv2.contourArea(contour) < 4000:
            continue

        (x,y, w, h)= cv2.boundingRect(contour)
        cv2.rectangle(frame, (x, y), (x + w, y + h),(0,225,0),3)


    cv2.imshow("Delta Frame",delta_frame)
    cv2.imshow("Capturing",gray)
    cv2.imshow("Threshold Frame",thresh_frame)
    cv2.imshow("Color Frame",frame)

    key = cv2.waitKey(5)

    if key==ord('q'):
        break

video.release()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

The code should be able to detect only moving object in the screen.

Comment: Please make your code reproducible.

Comment: Not familiar with the cv2 package, but it seems like `delta_frame = cv2.absdiff(first_frame,gray)` is essentially calling `absdiff(gray, gray)`, since the line before sets `first_frame=gray`. Is this the intended code, or do you mean `absdiff(frame, gray)`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had similar issue a while back when I started with opencv; the problem with the program is the first frame, the first frame captured a dark screen. The difference detected by cv2.absdiff of the first frame(first_frame) vs the next frames(gray) was big enough that the cv2.findContours was indicated on the whole screen. This may be caused by camera delay

It can be solved by incorporating a slight delay between when the camera load to when the program records the first frame(first_frame) with time.sleep(). Try this:

```
import cv2, time


first_frame = None

video = cv2.VideoCapture(0)
# the camera has some lag time hence the starting of video.read outside loop and sleep
video.read()
time.sleep(2)

while True:
    check, frame = video.read()

    gray = cv2.cvtColor(frame, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
    gray = cv2.GaussianBlur(gray, (21,21),0)

    if first_frame is None:
        first_frame=gray
        continue

    delta_frame = cv2.absdiff(first_frame,gray)
    thresh_frame = cv2.threshold(delta_frame, 30, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY)[1]
    thresh_frame = cv2.dilate(thresh_frame,None, iterations=2)

    (cnts,_) = cv2.findContours(thresh_frame.copy(), cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)

    for contour in cnts:
        if cv2.contourArea(contour) < 4000:
            continue

        (x,y, w, h)= cv2.boundingRect(contour)
        cv2.rectangle(frame, (x, y), (x + w, y + h),(0,225,0),3)


    cv2.imshow("Delta Frame",delta_frame)
    cv2.imshow("Capturing",gray)
    cv2.imshow("Threshold Frame",thresh_frame)
    cv2.imshow("Color Frame",frame)

    key = cv2.waitKey(5)

    if key==ord('q'):
        break

video.release()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

time.sleep takes care of the lag time of the camera starting.
Try the code, it worked here